# How to use HTML form input as JS variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make some element change color according to the number received from the form.

e.g. When a player types 2 in the form, there should be 2 colors from the 'color' array.

```js
function intro() {
  var num = document.getElementById('quant').value;
  var color = ["#FCB711", "#F37021", "#CC004C", "#6460AA", "#0080D0", "#0DB14B"];
  var i;

  for (i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
    document.getElementById('s' + i).style.backgroundColor = color[getRndInteger(0, num)];
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="tion" action="" method="get">
  Player (between 2 and 6):
  <input type="number" name="quant" min="2" max="6">
  <input type="button" value="start" onclick="intro()">
</form>
```

Comment: Start by giving your field an ID of quant and not just a name. getElementById is using ID

Comment: Where is  s1, s2, s3 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not showing relevant parts of your code, I've simplified it. Your input was missing an `id="quant"` which I added.

```js
function colorTheDiv() {
  const color = ["#FCB711", "#F37021", "#CC004C", "#6460AA", "#0080D0", "#0DB14B"];
  document.getElementById('colorMe').style.backgroundColor = color[parseInt(document.getElementById('quant').value)];
}
```

```html
<label for="quant">Player (between 2 and 6)</label>
<input type="number" name="quant" id="quant" min="2" max="6" onchange="colorTheDiv()">
<hr />
<div id="colorMe">colorMe</div>
```

I've also replaced the `button` and execute the `colorTheDiv` function whenever the value of `quant` changes (if you prefer you can still keep the button instead).

Comment: Where are the s1, s2, s3 etc?

Comment: @mplungjan Did you read my answer? *Because you're not showing relevant parts of your code, I've simplified it.*

Comment: @connexo it was such a simple mistake that i feel bad for asking this question in the first place.. Thank you very much!

Comment: The id=quant was already in my comment a few minutes after the question was asked

Answer (score 0):

Start by giving your field an ID of quant.
You are missing 42 elements too

I assume you ACTUALLY meant this

```js
var color = ["#FCB711", "#F37021", "#CC004C", "#6460AA", "#0080D0", "#0DB14B"];

function getRndInteger(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function intro() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "";
  var num = document.getElementById('quant').value;
  if (!num) {
    alert("Give a value")
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
    var col = color[getRndInteger(num)];
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = i;
    span.id = "s" + i;
    span.style.backgroundColor = col;
    container.appendChild(span)
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="tion" action="" method="get">
  Player (between 2 and 6):
  <input type="number" id="quant" min="2" max="6">
  <input type="button" value="start" onclick="intro()">
</form>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to give your field an ID of "quant" not just a name, otherwise `getElementByID` will return null